# Sub-functions to send and receive string over socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix, client-server

I assume that for messages that are of only 1 byte (a char), I will use read() and write() directly.

For those messages having size > 1 bytes, I use two subfunctions to read and write them over sockets.

For example, I have the server construct a string called strcities (list of city) and print it out --> nothing strange. Then send the number of bytes of this string to the client, and then the actual string.

The client will first read the number of bytes, then the actual city list.

For some reason my code sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. If it works, it also prints out some extra characters that I have no idea where they come from. If it doesn't, it hangs and forever waits in the client, while the server goes back to the top of the loop and wait for next command from the client.  Could you please take a look at my codes below and let me know where I did wrong?

Attempt_read

```
string attempt_read(int rbytes) { // rbytes = number of bytes of message to be read
    int count1, bytes_read;   
    char buffer[rbytes+1];
    bool notdone = true;   

    count1 = read(sd, buffer, rbytes); 

    while (notdone) {
        if (count1 == -1){
            perror("Error on write call");
            exit(1);
        }  
        else if (count1 < rbytes) {
            rbytes = rbytes - count1; // update remaining bytes to be read         
            count1 = read(sd, buffer, rbytes);
        }
        else {notdone = false;}
    }     // end while
    string returnme;
    returnme = string(buffer);
    return returnme;
}
```

Attempt_write

```
void attempt_write(string input1, int wbytes) { // wbytes = number of bytes of message 
    int count1;
    bool notdone = true; 

    count1 = write(sd, input1.c_str(), wbytes);

    while (notdone) {
        if (count1 == -1){
           perror("Error on write call");
           exit(1);
        }
        else if (count1 < wbytes) {    
           wbytes = wbytes - count1; 
           count1 = write(sd, input1.c_str(), wbytes);     
        }        
        else {notdone = false;}
    } // end while  
    return;  
}
```

Comment: Well I actually write and compile the code in C++ so thats why I guess I added the tag C++

Comment: It's a project assignment and the choices are C, C++ and Java. We chose C++

Comment: Yeah we're well aware of that. But I guess thats what we chose so we have to carry on with it

Comment: You need to test the `recv()/read()` result for zero explicitly. You aren't doing that so you will loop indefinitely at end of stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) string class has a method size() that will return the length of the string, so you do not actually need a second attempt_write parameter.

2) You can transfer length of message before message or you can transfer a terminating 0 after, if you only will sent an ASCII strings. Because your connection could terminate at any time, it is better to send exact length before sending the string, so your client could know, what to expect.

3) What compilator do you use, that would allow char buffer[rbytes+1]; ? A standard c++ would require char buffer = new char[rbytes+1]; and corresponding delete to avoid a memory leaks.

4) In your code, the second read function call use same buffer with no adjustment to length, so you, practically, overwrite the already received data and the function will only work, if all data will be received in first function call. Same goes for write function

I would suggest something like this:

```
void data_read(unsigned char * buffer, int size) {
    int readed, total = 0;

    do { 
    readed = read(sd, buffer + total, size - total);
    if (-1 == writted) {
        perror("Error on read call");
            exit(1);
        }

    total += readed;
    } while (total < size); 
}

string attempt_read() {  
    int size = 0;   
    data_read((unsigned char *) &size, sizeof(int));

    string output(size, (char) 0x0);

    data_read((unsigned char *) output.c_str(), size);

    return output;
} 

void data_write(unsigned char * buffer, int size) {
    int writted, total = 0;

    do { 
    writted = write(sd, buffer + total, size - total);
    if (-1 == writted) {
        perror("Error on write call");
            exit(1);
        }

    total += writted;
    } while (total < size); 
}

void attempt_write(string input) {  
    int size = input.size();    
    data_write((unsigned char *) &size, sizeof(int));
    data_write((unsigned char *) input.c_str(), size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
1. I do notice that thanks!
2. I think that is what I've been doing with my code. Send the size of the message first, then send the actual message
3. I'm not sure what you're asking?
4. I read the read man page http://linux.die.net/man/2/read, and it says that "On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number". So I assume that for attempt_read() I don't need to update the position of the buffer?

Comment: No, file position is a file device where you read from. You still need to adjust your own buffer position. As for "char buffer[rbytes+1];" standard C++ will not allow it, you should receive an error if you try to compile code like that. Static arrays are allocated at compilation time, so it length need to be known prior that. If you want dynamic array, you need to use new[] and delete[] operators or std::vecor, or, in case of text messages, std::string. And no, you code does not sent the size of message, all what you have been sending is a string it self.

Comment: Idk why but for some reason I didn't get the compile error for char buf[rbytes+1]? I compiled it on a UNIX server. Yeah I guess I didn't mention it clearly in my post that in the main function, I make 2 calls to this attempt_write/attempt_read, the first one to send/receive the size of the message and the 2nd call will send/receive the actual message.

Comment: I already submitted my work so there's nothing I can change, but it's great to learn something new! I guess I'll get into more details once I take the computer network class. Thanks!

Comment: @rustyengineer, You probably have an c++11 compilator.